# Using an air pump for an pneumatic forearm trainer

Tags: arduino, motor, physics, arduino-uno, air-pressure

I am attempting to create a forearm training device which  [looks like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09VKWKBB8) (I don't know what it's called). Can I use [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FHAEFD6) air pump motor with an arduino? It can provide pressure up to 100 kpa, but I don't understand how much that is physically. Are there any other alternatives I can/should use?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to share more plans for this design, this is more elaborate thing than you have cared to share. Secondly if you want to copy the design shown in posted picture, you will need to create a vacuum in the connectors which run across the fingers so that fingers can work against the vacuum. In that case this air pump wont do the job. Simpler approach would be to use this pump to blow up a rubber ball to a certain pressure controlled by Arduino (you will need a pressure sensor too). User can then control the pressure in the ball according to their workout needs. Needless to say there might be out of the box solutions for doing just that, like simpler finger trainers or hand grips for similar exercises.